# Setting Task Manager to Run VB Script

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, vba, taskmanager

I have having task manager call up a VB Script which opens an access document at a certain time everyday, and when this document opens it has VBA Code set up to export the file as a different file type. I am getting an error back that will not allow this to run in task manager. I am really confused, because this should be a really easy task it really is creating a new access program opening the document, and then quitting access. I know that the VBA Code in the access file is correct, because it works OK when the file is opened. Task manager is simple so I know it has to be something with my VB script being incorrect(formatting maybe?), because I double click it to run an I get an run error. I would just set task manager to open the access file, but it will not quit access so we went this way. Below is the code in my script.

```
 dim accessApp as variant
 set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
 accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("File Location")
 accessApp.Quit
 set accessApp = nothing
```

I did a few searches online already with little luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you test your VBScript from a command prompt using `cscript.exe`, it will tell you the line number and character position for the first error it detects.  That is usually a quick route to figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a type in your Dim statements with VBScript:

```
 dim accessApp
 set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
 accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("z:\docs\test.accdb")
 ''For testing purposes, comment out when testing is finished
 msgbox accessapp.name
 accessApp.Quit
 set accessApp = nothing
```

Comment: Wow sorry what a stupid mistake thanks I was going nuts trying to figure this thing out.

Comment: It happens to all of us :)